# How to remove null values from multiple columns in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

My dataset has around 200000 thousands of lines. Using the below command in PIG I'm trying to remove the null values but getting a wrong output. What am I missing here? Please help.

[image: Example]

I've used

```
div = Foreach dataset generate $43 as A,$44 as B,.....,$50 as H;
```

and trying to eliminate the null values to find the individual variable count as well as the total count.

```
values = filter div by A is not null AND B is not null AND C is not null AND D is not null AND E is not null AND F is not null AND G is not null AND H is not null;
```

And getting wrong output.

[image: Output]

I want the final output as something like H  1056  U  4355  W 999  P 1000  Y 2199

Comment: To me it is unclear what you really want to achieve. Can you give an example for input, expected and real output data?

Comment: @aventurin, I've edited the question. Please take a look

Comment: You've used the ˋANDˋ operator in your filter. So you are interested in all rows for which all columns are not ˋNULLˋ?

Comment: @aventurin, that's correct